# I cannot access a list I have created

Tags: c#

I am creating a console application that will generate random answers to Y/N questions. I need to have to use a list (not a dictionary) to read my responses in a simple text file. The problem is that the list I have created ( I have created it in the class) is not available for use, it is like I didn't create it.

I have tried double checking my syntax, closing Visual Studio and opening it again and making sure that I am putting it in the same class

```
//the below code is where I created the list
 class Program
    {
        // we need to create a list we can use
        List<string> Magicresponses = new List<string>();
//the below code is where I tried to use the list
private static void LoadMagic8responses()
        {
            // create a variable for our file
            StreamReader inputfile;
            try
            {
                inputfile = File.OpenText("8ball_file.txt");
                while (!inputfile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //this is where I am trying to use the list
```

The expectation was that I could just use the list I thought I could just start using the list but it is inaccessible in this custom method.

Comment: also, don't use streams for reading files. There is [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines), [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext) and [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes)

Answer (score 1):

Your `List` is declared as a member variable of the class `Program`, while the method `LoadMagic8responses` is static. You’ll want to study up on the difference between static and member variables/methods. Essentially, static methods execute outside of the context of any instance and so cannot access a member variable that only exists within the context of an instance.

Comment: Thanks. I figured the answer out a little later now I need to better understand static and member variable and methods.